# calculate an average with 2 variables

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a game in AS3.

I've got a toolbar with a string for money, one for happiness and one for tourists.

The happiness is coded like that :

```
var happyString:String = "0";
var happyNumber = Number(happyString);
bonheur.text = String(happyString); 
trace(happyString);
```

I'd like the "happy" value depends on two variables (invisibles for the player).

A variable "confort" and a variable "distraction".

And the **"happy" value would be = ("confort"+"distraction")/2**

I don't really know how to do it though...

I did that :

```
var confortString:String = "0";
var confortNumber = Number(confortString);

var distractionString:String = "0";
var distractionNumber = Number(distractionString);


stageRef.addEventListener("PiscineBuilt", piscineVariables, false, 0, true);

private function piscineVariables(event):void{
confortNumber = Number(confortString) +3;
trace(confortNumber);
distractionNumber = Number(distractionString) +20;
trace(distractionNumber);
    }
```

**First, I don't think the "confort" and "distraction" values are added each time the function is called...**

Second, How I can do in order to have the value "happy" (which is visible for the player in the toolbar) equal to ("confort"+"distraction")/2

```
        var happyString:String = distractionNumber + confortNumber ;
        var happyNumber = Number(happyString);
        bonheur.text = String(happyString); 
        trace(happyString);
```

??

Thank you for your help !

---

EDIT

So, here I am now :

```
             var confort:Number = 0;
             var distraction:Number = 0;
             var happy:Number = 0;

                        happy=(confort+distraction)/2;
            bonheur.text=String(happy);

stageRef.addEventListener("PiscineBuilt", piscineVariables, false, 0, true);

private function piscineVariables(event):void{
                confort+=10;
                distraction+=30;
                trace(confort);
                                trace(distraction);
                }
```

GOOD:

Forgot to change the value of my bonheur.text : 
bonheur.text = String( Number(bonheur.text ) +(confort+distraction)/2 );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you store strings and make numbers dependant on them? You just do:

```
var confort:Number = 0;
var distraction:Number = 0;
var happy:Number = 0;
```

And whenever your numbers are updated, you should also update the text in `bonheur`:

```
happy=(confort+distraction)/2; // making an average is as simple as this, if you're not using strings!!!
bonheur.text=String(happy);
```

Comment: Thank you. And for private function piscineVariables ? How do I put that confort is raised by 10 for exemple ?

Comment: You should learn syntax first. `confort += 3;` This means "add 3 to confort". Your code means "assign +3 (three) to confort".

Comment: Hmm...confort+=3; and distraction+=3; don't change anything in the value happy=(confort+distraction)/2;  Do you know why ?

Comment: You had to recalculate the value. I said *whenever*, this means once you change either value, you have to change the value in `happy` and `bonheur.text`. It's your job to make code flow so that the variable is reassigned correct value.